# Omnia vincit amor: vincere or vincire?

Tags: classical-latin, poetry, ambiguity, saying, vergilius

The phrase *omnia vincit amor* (from Vergilius' tenth Ecloga; see full text in [Latin](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0056%3Apoem%3D10) and [English](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0057%3Apoem%3D10)) is typically translated as "love conquers everything".
However, *vincit* can come from either *vincere* (to win) or *vincire* (to bind).
This leads to the alternative translation "love confines everything", which is also a meaningful statement.
This double meaning makes some sense in the context, too.
Is there evidence that this double meaning was observed in antiquity?
Has the phrase been used with both meanings?
Is there a good reason to believe that it should be read as *vincere* rather than *vincire*?

Comment: Surprising finding! Two ideas: 1) conquest is often followed by subjugation, enslavement, binding (especially in ancient times): both could be close, war-related analogies 2) [Col 3,14](http://biblehub.com/colossians/3-14.htm) is at times translated as "Love binds everything together in perfect harmony", whereas both the Vulgate and the [New Vulgate](http://www.vatican.va/archive/bible/nova_vulgata/documents/nova-vulgata_nt_epist-colossenses_lt.html#3) use the noun *vinculum*.

Comment: @Rafael: I don't understand your second point. *Vinculum* translates (quite literally) *sundesmos*, and I don't see how there is any ambiguity like in the OP's phrase.

Comment: @brianpck no ambiguity in the question: it was just a side comment. I looked up "love binds everything" in search for clues to answer and found that. I thought it was interesting to mention in the comments. The point was partly to point there was no _vincit_ behind that _binds_ too (FWIW)

Comment: One possible source for anyone who wants to write a new answer: Lawrence Durrell, "Tunc" page 21, "Vagina Vinctrix"

Comment: On a similar note, for a long time I assumed that 'province' came from 'vincere', but today discovered that in fact it is related to 'vincire'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a first point, you are certainly not the first person to recognize this. I found a [delightful little poem](https://books.google.com/books?id=sC5qzmxjLsUC&pg=PA8) composed in the 19th century by a certain Piré that uses this same word-play:

> **Omnia Vincit Amor**
>
> *Omnia vincit amor*; non est hoc simplice sensu
> Verum; cura duplex nascitur inde tibi:
> *Vincere* scit telis, roseis *vincire* catenis;
> Utcumque accipias, *omnia vincit amor*

This is not all, though: Varro, who was contemporary with Vergil (although born 40 years prior), develops this double-entendre:

> Hinc comicus:
>
> > Huic victrix Venus, videsne haec?
>
> Non quod vincere velit Venus, sed vincire. Ipsa Victoria ab eo quod superati vinciuntur. (Varro, De lingua latina, 5, 62)

It is hard to judge Vergil's actual intention, but it seems fairly clear from context that the primary sense is from *vincere*.

A few lines before the cited verse, he speaks of carving his initials on a tree so that they grow together:

> crescent illae, crescetis, amores.

The idea is of a love that will face all adversities. This is further developed in the verses immediately preceding, which speaks of various adversities the speak will endure (even if to no avail).

Finally, the juxtaposition with *cedere* favors the interpretation of *vincere*: if love conquers all, then we must yield to it. The step is less obvious (though, I admit, not implausible) if we see this as *vincire*.

Comment: I was convinced that I was not the first one to observe the double meaning. That quote from Varro is surprising. Isn't the perfect participle of *vincire* actually *vinctus*, not *victus*? I would expect *vinctrix* to be distinguishable from *victrix*.

Comment: I agree: given that L&S does not mention any classical usage of *vinctor*, I would hazard to guess that the average Roman ear wouldn't have too much trouble associating *victrix* and *vinctrix*. Shakespeare is rife with examples in English of similar puns.